# How to schedule the node js script to run automatically on windows?

Tags: node.js, node-schedule

This script

```
0 0/3 * * * node test.js
```

is used to schedule the job in Ubuntu, How to set the same way in Windows using node-schedule npm package?

As a work around , have scheduled the script in Task Scheduler:

```
cmd /c c:\node\node.exe c:\myscript.js
```

I want to to know how this can be done in node-schedule npm package.

Comment: What's wrong with just using Windows Task Scheduler?  I run multiple node.js programs via Task Scheduler.

Comment: I just want to know any other possible way using node-schedule npm package in Node JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://npmjs.org/package/node-schedule:

> Execute a cron job every 5 Minutes = */5 * * * *

So (according to the [NodeJS docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html)) you can use the `child_process` npm module to run the script.

Like this:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

schedule.scheduleJob('*/5 * * * *', function() {
  spawn('node', ['test.js']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'cron' package for schedule functions on nodejs - 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

According it's [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

> Cron is a tool that allows you to execute something on a schedule.
>   This is typically done using the cron syntax. We allow you to execute
>   a function whenever your scheduled job triggers.

Usage example

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

const exampleJob = new CronJob(`*/2 * * * * *`,()=>{
    console.log("You will see this message every 2 seconds",new Date().getSeconds());
});

exampleJob.start();
```

for addition if you not familiar with cron schedule expressions(cron syntax) that web will help you get right expression
https://crontab.guru/